# Dynamically set size of HTML element (using Zurb Foundation 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I have this div (it could be a span, or other non-clickable element if we like).  It's messageAlertBox.

```
<div id="messageModal" class="medium reveal-modal">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="messageAlertBox" class="alert-box"></div>
        <div class="small-6 large-6 columns"><p id="messageText" class="lead"></p></div>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">x</a>
</div>
```

Then I do the following to it:

```
function notifyUser(alertType, messageText) {
    if (alertType === 'Success') {
        $('#messageAlertBox').addClass('success');
    } else if (alertType === 'Error') {
        $('#messageAlertBox').addClass('alert');
    }

    $('#messageAlertBox').html(alertType);
    $('#messageText').html(messageText);
    openModal = 'messageModal';
}
```

Where "alertType" may be a string of unknown length.

What's happening is that messageAlertBox is as wide as it's containing element.  I have messed with this a lot, and if it is not max wide, I have managed to get it to be too narrow.  Basically just [].

I need this element to be as wide as the string alertType (plus a little).  I thought span would do that automagically but I guess I was wrong.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Div's automatically take up the whole width of the page unless otherwise specified.

in your css, for the div (or the class)

try  adding this: (could use div, or your id)

```
div
{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

The default display value is block, which doesn't allow for elements to be placed beside it.

inline-block sets the width to "what it needs to use" and prevents the div from taking the entire width of the page.

If it's just text, display:inline should work too, either one :)

Comment: Span, if I remember right, is inline.  I have tried replacing the div with  a span and removing the jQuery.html('span wrapper.  This also takes up the entire row.

Comment: if (alertType === 'Success') {
        $('#messageAlertBox').addClass('success');
    } else if (alertType === 'Error') {
        $('#messageAlertBox').addClass('alert'); Can you post the css for these and alert-box?

Comment: That's standard zurb foundation.

Comment: Ahh I see, this is a CSS issue. I don't know zurb foundation, but if it affects or overrides the positioning, then the style won't necessarily take. The fact that the class says alert-box hints to me that it does have some positioning styles. The display suggestions we suggested are syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wand #messageAlertBox to be as wide as the span plus a little padding? You can do that by just setting it to display: block (or inline-block if you prefer):

```
div {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vaAJB/2/

Comment: Which works, except that it breaks zurb's foundation and ends up at the end of the row.  Close tho

Comment: just use the id rather than element selector. So #messageAlertBox { display: inline;}

Comment: I had added the style="display:inline" to the specific element, not to the div class.

Comment: if it isn't working, then it is other CSS that you are using that is interfering with it. It will be impossible to debug without seeing the CSS that is breaking it.

Comment: Exactly, also I believe adding the css to the id is more 'specific' than the inline style modifier and would override it? I think, I don't use html inline styles.

Comment: inline styles are the highest specificity, except adding "!important" to a declaration.

Comment: All of the classes in this code are standard zurb foundation.  I did try your inline style on the messageAlertBox div, and it did fix the width - but it broke the zurb row class by causing the messageAlertBox to float to the right side of the row.

Comment: you'll need to include the zurb css (and markup) that broke, so we have any chance of knowing why it broke.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
<div class="small-1 large-1 columns"><span id="messageAlertBox" class="alert-box" style="display: inline;"></span></div>
```

The small-1 columns div positions the contents in the correct place in the row.  The contents are spanned to the size of the text with the inline style.

This solution is responsive to browser window size without violating the constraint of the text size.